# Calculating a mathematical formula using For Loops but did not get the right result

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

First of all, apologize if the title is not so specific as I have a hard time finding the appropriate title name.

I am trying to calculate numbers in two sets of lists by using For Loops
this is the code that I used:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 4, 6]

for num in x:
    a = (num + 1)
    for n in y:
        b = n+a
        print(b)
        break
```

The result that I am hoping for is this:

```
4 
7 
10
```

however, the result that I am getting is:

```
4
5
6
```

can anyone help me with this? thank you

Comment: Why have the inner loop if you're going to break out in the first iteration?

Comment: I think you want to replace for num in x with: for num, n in zip(x, y):
This way you iterate to both lists with the same steps . 
Also remove the break. 
How you do it now you loop only the first value of y with every step of x because of the break. If you only remove the break you will loop through every value of y for each step in x

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop always takes the first element of y (2) to do the sum with, not the same index element as the first, either use enumerate instead of your for loop which will give you the index you're operating with and use that as a lookup to the other list...

```
for idx, num in enumerate(x):
    a = (num + 1)
    n = y[idx]
    b = n+a
    print(b)
```

or you can zip the two lists together to iterate over their indices in pairs

```
for num, n in zip(x,y):
    a = (num + 1)
    b = n+a
    print(b)
```